# Hadoop real world examples with jar files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am trying to find some real time use cases of hadoop/mapreduce - I hav already tried examples like wordcount , sudoku solver which come with the distro

are there any such examples - which are not part of the distro.....

thanks!
SAi

Comment: You can read Donald Miner's book "MapReduce Design Patterns", which comes with java source code.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below the links for the real world Implementations of mapreduce

1. [Some examples of using financial data in MapReduce programs.](https://github.com/eljefe6a/FinancialMapReduce)
2. [MMPROG game](http://ayende.com/Blog)
3. [Mapreduce for Transactions](https://github.com/rathboma/hadoop-framework-examples)
4. [Logistic Regression with R running on Hadoop](https://github.com/vilcek/R_MapReduce_Logistic_Regression)
5. [MapReduce Pattern Examples](https://github.com/lumartin/MapReduce-Patterns)
6. [Examples about GPars, parallel methods, map/reduce, actors](https://github.com/mariogarcia/gpars-examples)

Answer (score 0):

some example program you can also try this.

http://everythingbigdata.blogspot.in/2012/05/apache-hadoop-map-reduce-advanced.html

http://www.higherpass.com/java/Tutorials/Building-Hadoop-Mapreduce-Jobs-In-Java/1/